# ping to service IP in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to k8s and wondering why we can not ping to svc in Kubernetes but we can ping to node and pod clusterIP. Can someone help to explain?

```
controlplane $ kubectl get pods,svc -o wide
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/nginx   1/1     Running   0          4m52s   192.168.1.4   node01   <none>           <none>

NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE     SELECTOR
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   9d      <none>
service/nginx-service   ClusterIP   10.100.109.11   <none>        80/TCP    4m51s   app.kubernetes.io/name=proxy
```

b) ping to svc IP

```
controlplane $ ping 10.100.109.11
PING 10.100.109.11 (10.100.109.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.100.109.11 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2050ms
```

c) curl to svc IP

```
curl 10.100.109.11:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```

Comment: @Luuk Thank you. Yes, I understand we can not ping to svc IP since it is a virtual IP but if I ping it from inside pod then I can ping to svc IP. This is where I am getting confused.